# Push method for core motion and frequency of Accelerometer/Gyroscope Data

Tags: iphone, core-motion

When push method is used to get accelerometer/gyroscope/device motion data, unfortunately the gyroscope and the device motion maximum frequency cannot exceed 72Hz on average (in fact the data is not periodic at all either).

Even worse, if only the gyroscope data is recorded (without starting device motion update service: i.e. using only [motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:opQ withHandler:gyroHandler]), then the gyroscope data frequency drops to 52Hz on average.

Has anyone tried to obtain gyroscope data at 100Hz using pull method? Can we reach the maximum 100Hz throughput with the "pull method"?

Furthermore, did anyone check whether this faulty behavior is corrected in ios 4.2 (beta)?

Comment: I found out a maximum of 75 Hz on iOS 4.2 (using CMDeviceMotion)