# iPhone - core motion rotationRate

Tags: iphone, core-motion

Using just the rotationRate property of Core Motion or Gyroscope is it possible to extract how much radians (or degrees if you like) the device rotated?

I have tried to do a timed sampled of Core Motion data, for example, sampling it 5 times per second so I know that there's 0.2seconds between each reading. Then if I have a rotationRate of 0.5 radians per second from one read to another, in theory I could divide this by 5 and know now much radians the device rotated since the last time.

This seems logical, but the results have nothing to do with reality. Rotating the device 90 degrees will produce results telling me that the device rotated 100 times less than that.

Is it possible to extract how much the device rotated just by looking at rotationRate?

What am I missing?

Comment: Degree - Radians? Right angle according to device orientation?

Comment: what do you mean? I don't care if it is radians or degrees. I just want to know how much degrees de device rotated in each axis. Using Yaw, pitch and roll is not good, because pitch just varies from -Pi to Pi. So, I am trying to see if I can extract the relative rotation in 3 axis from this rotationRate...

Comment: I happened to notice that this is very similar to a previous question you asked. Is the reason you didn't go with Euler Angles from CMAttitude because "pitch just varies from -Pi to Pi"?

Comment: No, it is because I was receiving wild values and I would like to try a different approach, in order to see if the values are more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need more space than a comment ;-) iOS retrieves all data in radians and if your other calculations are correct, I thought it might be the angle measured in radians.

In general your approach seems to be alright: Take every signal's angle velocity, multiply it with time delta and you will have the angle delta for this timeframe. Then sum all your angles and the result should be the covered distance as angle in radians. Angle phi is the integral of angle velocity omega over the elapsed time and doing numerical integration with the trapezoidal rule (i.e. like described) is OK for gyroscope's data (not for accelerometer).

In general I would recommend to use the timestamp delivered by core motion instead of the defined period (1/5) as recommended by Apple, because device motion data is often delivered in a lower frequency than expected (see [What is the official iPhone 4 maximum gyroscope data update frequency and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790111/what-is-the-official-iphone-4-maximum-gyroscope-data-update-frequency/4808933#4808933) or [Push method for core motion and frequency of Accelerometer/Gyroscope Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885556/push-method-for-core-motion-and-frequency-of-accelerometer-gyroscope-data).

Furthermore you should take a higher frequency to avoid errors in your numerical integration.

**[Update from comments section:]**

If your are interested in integrating via extended Simpson's Rule I recommend this [paper](http://einstein.informatik.uni-oldenburg.de/forschung/integration/IntUndDiffUngleichungenUV.pdf) (German only, p. 173 ff.) and [An Extension to Newton-Cotes Formulae](http://einstein.informatik.uni-oldenburg.de/forschung/integration/Integration-engl.pdf). Some sample code as extracted snippet taken from an existing project can be found here: [DevicePosition.m](http://files.scio.de/code-snippets/DevicePosition.m) Note that it might not compile, no warranty, as is, ... you know this from other sites ;-)

A free app displaying sensor input as graphs for iPhone: [Sensor Monitor](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sensor-monitor/id381075251?mt=8)

Comment: thanks. I have tried using the official timestamps but the big problem is this. My method does this. WHen it starts it takes a reading of the initial attitude and I calculate the device rotation. Lets say the iphone is at rest and the angle read says 0 degrees. Then I rotate it 180 degrees. While it is rotating, the routine does this: reads the difference between timestamps (the current and the last) - lets call this delta, reads rotationRate, divides it by delta. So now it knows how much it rotated since last time.... continues

Comment: if I rotate the device 180 degrees in one axis and back to the original position, the sum of all deltas should be zero, but isn't. The original position that was reported as being zero is now reported incorrectly... for example a 180 degrees rotation is reported as being  150 degrees more or less...

Comment: Ah, "divides by delta"? rate*time = angle. velocity/time = acceleration. Sorry I misread your question (you stated it already) and assumed 1/5 sec as time delta to multiply. May be that's it :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I meant multiply by delta. Unfortunately I am multiplying by delta and the range is reported as 150 degrees more or less for a real 180 degrees rotation and every time you rotate, a different angle is reported. I will continue trying to discover ways. Thanks.

Comment: what I discovered in this process is that you cannot trust rotationRate as an indication of rotation direction when the rotation is small. In theory, rotationRates comes with a plus sign when the rotation is anti-clock wise and with a minus sign when it is clockwise (right hand rule). But this is not true when the rotation is small, even using Core Motion unbiased data.

Comment: I don't think so. Have a look at this graph, just recorded from iPhone4 with a very decent low pass filter (=0.9) and frequency about 75Hz: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/658954/RotationRate_LowPass0.9.jpg . I did a very small rotation and this is zoomed in. What you see is just my own overshooting (correct English?) when I decelerate from vMax to 0. If I am really concentrated on the motion, I manage to avoid this.

Comment: This is not happening to me. Can you please send me this app you did for test, so I can see how you did it? Perhaps it is something related to the low pass filter... thanks

Comment: I was not talking about the whole project but just how you are sampling and filtering, but never mind. So I am right when I say rotationRate is not trustable. If you had to develop your own framework to make the detection work is a signal that apple's is faulty. Thanks.

Comment: My framework interpretes the sensor input on a higher level for detecting different predefined motions using AI like learning and so on. I used rotationRate for dynamic parts i.e. that need not know exact position at the end. This works excellent because I am only interested in velocity. For those parts that need exact position information I used CMAttitude's  quaternion representation (rotation matrix will do it as well). I use Simpson rule with non equidistant time intervals and it is one from the few ugly coded classes (out of 80). Simplifying it to linear integration leads to ...

Comment: phi(n) = SUM(rotRate(n) * deltaTime(n))

Comment: The moderators hate long comment threads, but this was very insightful and hopefully they will not delete it. Unfortunately, they tend to think that written rules supersede anyone's opinion or case-by-case judgment. Would you mind re-posting your DevicePosition code? The dropbox links are dead.

Comment: I updated the answer and dropped some of my comments. Accidentally I deleted the picture but I leave the comment anyway because of other stuff.